# XSLT 1.0 add element with attribute if it doesn't exist

Tags: xslt, attributes, addition, element

How can I add an element with attribute if it doesn't exist in the xml file. I would like to add

```
<c name="EX1">testing</c>
```

to each "m" node if it does not exist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<h>
  <m>
    <c name="HM">G</c>
    <c name="HL">20</c>
    <c name="HS">f</c>
  </m>
  <m>
    <c name="HM">L</c>
    <c name="HL">30</c>
    <c name="HS">t</c>
  </m>
  <m>
    <c name="HM">S</c>
    <c name="HL">10</c>
    <c name="HS">t</c>
    <c name="EX1">testing</c>
  </m>
</h>
```

Here is my xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my desired output

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <h>
      <m>
        <c name="HM">G</c>
        <c name="HL">20</c>
        <c name="HS">f</c>
        <c name="EX1">testing</c>
      </m>
      <m>
        <c name="HM">L</c>
        <c name="HL">30</c>
        <c name="HS">t</c>
        <c name="EX1">testing</c>
      </m>
      <m>
        <c name="HM">S</c>
        <c name="HL">10</c>
        <c name="HS">t</c>
        <c name="EX1">testing</c>
      </m>
    </h>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show any XSLT you have tried so far, even if it is just the identity template. Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean the `<c name="EX1">` nodes need to be added to the `m` elements, rather than `h`? Also showing your expected output would help. Thanks!

Comment: You're correct, I have update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the identity template being used, all you need to do is add a second template matching `m` elements (I am assuming you meant `m` not `h` here) where the required node does not exist, like so

```
<xsl:template match="m[not(c[@name='EX1' and text()='testing'])]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    <c name="EX1">testing</c>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, much appreciated